# Gradle - Add specific folder to JAR with different java source/compile version

Tags: java, gradle, build, jar

I have a Gradle project where I want to expose the request/response folder out for another project to consume.
My project is running in java 11. and its structure is like this

```
src
  main
    java
      com.xxx
        request
        response
        service
        controller
```

I only want to expose src.main.java.com.xxx.request/response with java 8.
How should I do that?

below is my NOT working Gradle build

```
task generateJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes("Implementation-Title": "Gradle", "Implementation-Version": "0.0.1")
    }
    from('src/main/java') {
        include '**/request/**'
        include '**/response/**'
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not a `Copy` task ?

Answer (score 0):

create a muilti_project, put your request/response code into to a lib subproject and declare the dependencies.

check [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) and [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html) out.